# How to remove lines added above and below table when using tex4ht?

Tags: tables, tex4ht

tex4ht for some reasons added extra horizontal lines above and below each `table`. While these lines do not show in pdf.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

This is my table

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}\hline
A & B \\\hline
853.075 (sec) & 43.711 (sec)\\\hline
14.218 (minutes) & 0.729 (minutes)\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

my table is done    
\end{document}
```

Compiled using `lualatex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But compiled using `make4ht  foo.tex "htm"`  gives extra horizontal lines above and below the table, which I did not ask for

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\Configure{float}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="float">}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It is based on the original `tex4ht` code, only the horizontal rules were removed.

The result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if a figure environment is used, but the horizontal lines still appear.